# Using a relative path to reference another element in a multi dimensional array in Ansible-YAML

Tags: yaml, jinja2, ansible

I have a multidimensional array that's defined in YAML syntax. This is part of a group_vars file that's used by Ansible:

```
mirrors:
  - name: "ubuntu"
    dists: 
      - precise
      - precise-backports
      - precise-proposed
      - precise-security
      - precise-updates
    frontend_uri: "/ubuntu"
    package_pattern: "/ubuntu/pool"
    sync_hour: 0
    upstreams:
      main: "nl.archive.ubuntu.com"
      backups:
        - "ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke"
        - "ke.archive.ubuntu.com"
```

What bothers me is that `mirrors[0].frontend_uri` and `mirrors[0].package_pattern` could be generated out of `mirrors[0].name`, but to do this I would need to somehow reference them using a relative path because i don't want to include the iterator of the first level (`0`) into the path, more or less like this:

```
mirrors:
  - name: "ubuntu"
    dists: 
      - precise
      - precise-backports
      - precise-proposed
      - precise-security
      - precise-updates
    frontend_uri: "/{{ .name }}"
    package_pattern: "/{{ .name }}/pool"
    sync_hour: 0
    upstreams:
      main: "nl.archive.ubuntu.com"
      backups:
        - "ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke"
        - "ke.archive.ubuntu.com"
```

Is there any way to reference other parts of a multi dimensional array using a relative path?

Comment: Are you saying that you can write: `frontend_uri: "/{{ mirrors[0].name }}"` ? I don't think that's possible, see [Keep Ansible DRY: How to avoid repeating variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22027902/272735).

Comment: I didn't mean to say that, since I thought it would be a bad idea to do that I haven't even tried if it works. Thanks for the link, so unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a perfectly nice solution

Answer (score 4):

This would work:
The *name is a yamlism that allows to use a defined alias with &
The rest are just using a variable reference not defined in the same tree.

```
_name: &name "ubuntu"
- name: *name
    dists: 
      - precise
      - precise-backports
      - precise-proposed
      - precise-security
      - precise-updates
    frontend_uri: "/{{ _name }}"
    package_pattern: "/{{ _name }}/pool"
    sync_hour: 0
    upstreams:
      main: "nl.archive.ubuntu.com"
      backups:
        - "ubuntu.mirror.ac.ke"
        - "ke.archive.ubuntu.com"
```

Comment: I understood "ubuntu" is just one example and there could be n elements. Defining a variable with the content "ubuntu" doesn't help with simplification because you would need to define n variables and use them in `package_pattern` etc accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is nice way to do this in group_vars other than @bcoca's answer.

But if you use a helper list and a `set_fact` task you could generate those variables dinamically.

I simplified your example list and added another element. Here it is:

```
mirrors_base:
  - name: "ubuntu"
    sub_element_a: "a"
    sub_element_b: "b"

  - name: "centos"
    sub_element_a: "a"
    sub_element_b: "b"
```

I renamed it to `mirrors_base` and I'll generate the final `mirrors` from this. Here is the `set_fact` task:

```
- name: Creating mirrors list
  set_fact:
    mirrors: "{{ mirrors | default([]) + [extra_elements] }}"
  with_items: "{{ mirrors_base }}"
  vars:
    _frontend_uri: "/{{ item.name }}"
    _package_pattern: "/{{ item.name }}/pool"
    extra_elements: "{{ item | combine({'frontend_uri': _frontend_uri ,'package_pattern': _package_pattern}) }}"

- name: Display the result
  debug:
    var: mirrors
```

We iterate over `mirros_base`.

The set_fact main body in details:

- `mirrors | default([])`: I check if `mirrors` variable defined and if it isn't, it will use an empty list. I only need this, because `mirrors` does not exist on the first iteration. Further details on `default()` is [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values).
- `+`: List  concatenation.
- `[extra_elements]`: putting `extra_element` variable in a list.

The set_fact vars:

- `_frontend_uri` and `_package_pattern` are helper variables defining the pattern.
- `extra_elements` is the dictionary we put mirros_base and the new vars merged.
- `item`: is the iteration variable and it contains an element from `mirros_base`.
- `combine()`: Is used to merge dictionarys into one. Inside, we define a dictionary for the keys, then use the helper variables for the values. Further details on `combine()` is [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/combine_filter.html).

Result:

```
TASK [Display the result] ********************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mirrors": [
        {
            "frontend_uri": "/ubuntu",
            "name": "ubuntu",
            "package_pattern": "/ubuntu/pool",
            "sub_element_a": "a",
            "sub_element_b": "b"
        },
        {
            "frontend_uri": "/centos",
            "name": "centos",
            "package_pattern": "/centos/pool",
            "sub_element_a": "a",
            "sub_element_b": "b"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that this is not in the original question but,

What if we want to define `frontend_uri` for example to be a specific value for `centos` because some reason. We can't do it because this method will overwrite the vaule.

But we can change the `_frontend_uri` variable line to be:

```
_frontend_uri: "{{ item.frontend_uri | default('/' + item.name) }}"
```

This will keep the defined value and we can set it to whatever in `mirros_base`.
Here is the updated `group_vars` with this modification:

```
mirrors_base:
  - name: "ubuntu"
    sub_element_a: "a"
    sub_element_b: "b"

  - name: "centos"
    sub_element_a: "a"
    sub_element_b: "b"
    frontend_uri: "/centos8"
```

The task:

```
- name: Creating mirrors list
  set_fact:
    mirrors: "{{ mirrors | default([]) + [extra_elements] }}"
  with_items: "{{ mirrors_base }}"
  vars:
    _frontend_uri: "{{ item.frontend_uri | default('/' + item.name) }}"
    _package_pattern: "{{ item.package_pattern | default('/' + item.name + '/pool') }}"
    extra_elements: "{{ item | combine({'frontend_uri': _frontend_uri ,'package_pattern': _package_pattern}) }}"


- name: Display the result
  debug:
    var: mirrors
```

And the result:

```
TASK [Display the result] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "mirrors": [
        {
            "frontend_uri": "/ubuntu",
            "name": "ubuntu",
            "package_pattern": "/ubuntu/pool",
            "sub_element_a": "a",
            "sub_element_b": "b"
        },
        {
            "frontend_uri": "/centos8",
            "name": "centos",
            "package_pattern": "/centos/pool",
            "sub_element_a": "a",
            "sub_element_b": "b"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope this helped.